# Existence of regular functions satisfying $f(P)=g(Q)=0$ and $f + g = 1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety and $P,Q\in X$ be two distinct points. I want to show that there exists regular functions $f,g$ such that $f(P)=0=g(Q)$ and $f(R)+g(R)=1$ for all $R\in X$.

If we want this to hold, then we must have $f(Q)=1$ and $g(P)=1$. My idea was to find explicit functions and prove that they are regular. But I didn't succeed.

I also know that since $X$ is an affine variety (say W.L.O.G. that $X\subset\mathbb{A}^{n}$) we have $\mathcal{O}_{X}(X)\cong k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]/I(X)$. So it is enough to find functions living in the rightside of this isomorphism with the desired properties.

Comment: Unless $X=\Bbb A^1$, it doesn't make any sense to ask for $f+g=id$. Do you mean $f+g=1$, or something else?

Comment: You are completely right, I indeed meant $f+g=1$. I will change it in the question.

Comment: Here are some hints: Do you see how to finish this if you have a function $h$ with $h(P)=0$ and $h(Q)\neq 0$? Do you see how to argue that such an $h$ must exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, given an affine algebraic variety $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n_k$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, and two distinct points $P$ and $Q$ inside it, you search for a regular function $f$ such that $f(P)=0$, $f(Q)=1$.

As $P \neq Q$, there is a $i$ such that $x_i(P) \neq x_i(Q)$. Then consider $f(R) = \frac{x_i(R)-x_i(P)}{x_i(Q)-x_i(P)}$ which clearly is regular on $X$.